# Register a Servlet bean in Grails 3 applications

Tags: servlets, grails, spring-boot, zk, grails-3.0

I have a limited knowledge of how Bean registration work in Grails 3.

What I am trying to do is to register a Servlet bean for ZK inside `init/package/Application.groovy`. The bean is reported to be already registered but I cannot get the mapping URL (`*.zul`) work. I am not sure what's wrong with the code. Here's what I have in `Application.groovy`:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dHtmlLayoutServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean reg = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DHtmlLayoutServlet())
        reg.setLoadOnStartup(1)
        reg.setInitParameters(["update-uri":"/zkau"])
        reg.addUrlMappings("*.zul", "*.zhtml")
        reg.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        return reg
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dHtmlUpdateServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean reg = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DHtmlUpdateServlet())
        reg.setLoadOnStartup(2)
        reg.addUrlMappings("/zkau/*")
        reg.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        return reg
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to following site, don't you?

http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2015/12/integrating-zk-framework-on-a-spring-boot-application/

Your configuration works fine for me.

Where do you place `*.zul`?
DHtmlLayoutServlet doesn't search `grails-app/views/*.zul` but `src/main/webapp/*.zul`.

*My Environment*

- Grails 3.2.3
- ZK 8:

  ```
  // ZK Framework
  compile "org.zkoss.zk:zkplus:8.0.2.2"
  compile "org.zkoss.zk:zkbind:8.0.2.2"
  // ZK Spring
  compile "org.zkoss.zk:zkspring-core:3.1.1"
  ```